# Woocommerce subscriptions process renewal using rest API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions, renewal

I'm doing a custom built admin section for wordpress using rest API. I got all options except processing renewal subscriptions using rest API.

Is there any possible option to do renewal processing using rest API?

I'm referring to this docs: https://prospress.github.io/subscriptions-rest-api-docs/

Any help will be appreciated.

--
Thanks in Advance
Tibin Mathew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by setting the renewal date to the very next minute and update. Then the cron job will do the rest!..